# Check if element has class, if does add it to n element - but dynamically

Tags: javascript

I want to add class to my button when my product is out of stock. 
I have a simple `<select>`. When one of the selected `<option>` products is out of stock, `someother-element` is given class `out-of-stock`. 
Is there a way to add a class or a tag to button every time `someother-element` has class `out-of-stock` and remove it when it doesn't?

Here is a link to simple codepen https://codepen.io/ivica-ha/pen/MMWzQZ

Problem with my code is, it only checks once DOM is ready, but the change will happen more than once.

```
<label for="pet-select">Choose a pet:</label>

<select id="pet-select">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
    <option value="parrot">Parrot</option>
    <option value="spider">Spider</option>
    <option value="goldfish">Goldfish</option>
</select>

<div class="someother-element out-of-stock"></div>
<button class="btn">Button text</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($(".someother-element").hasClass("out-of-stock")) {
    //alert('Has class');
    $(".btn").addClass("myClass");
  };
});
</script>
```

Comment: Put the code in a named function, and call it whenever you do something that changes the `out-of-stock` class.

Comment: Tell us when `.out-of-stock` could be given to your element. When `#pet-select` changes? After an AJAX call?

Comment: Or create a function that's used to add the `out-of-stock` class, and put this code in that function.

Answer (score 0):

Add a change handler for the select. 
Something like this.

```
$("#pet-select").on('change', function(e) {
      //you can also check for the selected option here and do the DOM changes
      if($(".someother-element").hasClass("out-of-stock")) {
        //alert('Has class');
        $(".btn").addClass("myClass");
      };
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("select").on("change",function(){
  console.log($('select :selected').hasClass('out-of-stock'))
 if($('select :selected').hasClass('out-of-stock')){
       $("button").addClass("myclass")
}

  else{
    $("button").removeClass("myclass")
} 
})
```

```css
button.myclass{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="pet-select">Choose a pet:</label>

<select id="pet-select">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat" class="out-of-stock">Cat</option>
    <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
    <option value="parrot">Parrot</option>
    <option value="spider" class="out-of-stock">Spider</option>
    <option value="goldfish">Goldfish</option>
</select>
<button class="btn">Button text</button>
```

added class="out-of-stock" for option return if the selected option has this class!